# iOS crashes when using UIImagePickerController to present the camera view

Tags: ios, crash, uiimagepickercontroller

In iOS, when I use UIImagePickerController to present the camera view, my app crashes. This occurs on iOS 8, 7 and iPhone 5s, and 5c.

Here is the code I used:

```
UIImagePickerController *imagePickerC = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imagePickerC.sourceType = type;
imagePickerC.delegate = self;
imagePickerC.allowsEditing = NO;
[self presentViewController:imagePickerC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Here is the crash stack:

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x40a07, 0x0000000194bd40a8 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = breakpoint 1.2 14.1
frame #0: 0x0000000194bd40a8 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_throw
frame #1: 0x0000000182e3bb34 CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:] + 224
frame #2: 0x00000001896dbf64 CameraKit`-[CAMFocusView _fadeOutIfNeeded] + 164
frame #3: 0x00000001897394bc CameraKit`-[CAMPreviewView focusDidEnd] + 140
frame #4: 0x00000001897006f4 CameraKit`-[CAMCameraView _updatePreviewForFocusDidEnd] + 44
frame #5: 0x00000001897005b0 CameraKit`-[CAMCameraView cameraControllerFocusDidEnd:] + 32
frame #6: 0x000000018974ed4c CameraKit`-[CAMCaptureController _focusCompleted] + 244
frame #7: 0x0000000189751254 CameraKit`__71-[CAMCaptureController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:]_block_invoke + 956
frame #8: 0x00000001897505e4 CameraKit`-[CAMCaptureController _runOnMainThreadImmediatelyIfPossibleWithBlock:] + 68
frame #9: 0x0000000189750e48 CameraKit`-[CAMCaptureController observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 200
frame #10: 0x0000000183da7218 Foundation`-[NSKeyValueObservance observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 468
frame #11: 0x0000000183d815c4 Foundation`NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 340
frame #12: 0x0000000183d810e4 Foundation`NSKeyValueDidChange + 460
frame #13: 0x0000000183d6a88c Foundation`-[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 116
frame #14: 0x000000018179f1f4 AVFoundation`-[AVCaptureFigVideoDevice _handleNotification:payload:] + 900
frame #15: 0x0000000182f1027c CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 20
frame #16: 0x0000000182f0f384 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 312
frame #17: 0x0000000182f0d9a8 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 1756
frame #18: 0x0000000182e392d4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
frame #19: 0x000000018c8976fc GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 168
frame #20: 0x0000000187a36f40 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 1488
frame #21: 0x000000010038452c beibei`main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016fd2b9d0) + 248 at main.m:29
frame #22: 0x000000019527ea08 libdyld.dylib`start + 4
```

All of this is the system function, and the last point is `__NSArrayI objectAtIndex`.

Comment: try this code  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    
    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

Comment: @DarjiJigar perhaps leave that as an answer instead? Would allow for an easier format and space for an explaination.

Comment: thanks for your comment, i cry this code, but also crashed, and the stack is the same

Comment: @DarjiJigar How is that code any different than what the OP posted?

Comment: @rmaddy compare both code

Comment: add  <UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate> delegate method in .h file

Comment: @DarjiJigar I did, that's why I asked. All you did was rename the variable and reorder the lines. And you allowed editing. So again, how is that supposed to fix the issue?

Comment: @DarjiJigar Adding those protocols won't do anything. That's only useful at compile time and will have no effect at runtime.

Comment: @rmaddy when the UIImagePickerController presented, wait for seconds, it crashed

Answer (score 0):

I have pick the camera image and the source is given below, its working for me,

```
if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {

        UIAlertView *myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                              message:@"Device has no camera"
                                                             delegate:nil
                                                    cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                    otherButtonTitles: nil];

        [myAlertView show];

    }
    else
    {
        UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        photoPicker.delegate = self;
        photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        photoPicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        photoPicker.allowsEditing = YES;
        [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
```

And also get the image from gallery code is given below, its also working for me,

```
UIImagePickerController *photoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    photoPicker.delegate = self;
    photoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:photoPicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Don't forget the framework AssetsLibrary (Example - `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>`)

Hope its helpful..

Comment: it works well on most iphones, but just crash on 5s,5c and ios 8.4, so i confused

Comment: this code work well iphone 5, 5s but i don't check 5c, and this code work properly, i think you are confused.